Why the Har Sinai experience had to be so negative?
I had a conversation about the Haredi world, and I was pointed out that the Receiving of the Torah on Mt. Sinai, the founding event in the history of the Jewish people, was also a dreadful and frightening experience just like the rest of the Haredi conduct (Haredi meaning "being frightened" in Hebrew).
I've reread the chapter, and indeed, it starts with God threatening to kill anyone who derails from his strict rules, and continues to describe the Jewish people as being in a constant state of anxiety and fear (ויחרד) during the whole show, up to the point when they can't stand it anymore and retreat.
The Rabbinic interpretation in Shabbos 88a also depicts a bleaky picture:

"Rabbi Avdimi bar Ḥama bar Ḥasa said: the Jewish people actually stood beneath the mountain, and the verse teaches that the Holy One, Blessed be He, overturned the mountain above the Jews like a tub, and said to them: If you accept the Torah, excellent, and if not, there will be your burial.
Rav Aḥa bar Ya’akov said: From here there is a substantial caveat to the obligation to fulfill the Torah. The Jewish people can claim that they were coerced into accepting the Torah, and it is therefore not binding.
"

Was this negative experience a necessity? Could Har Sinai revelation be fun and a happy and positive experience for all participants? Couldn't the air be filled with flowers and serpentine instead of bolts of lightning, and couldn't they hear the voice of violins instead of war-summoning Shofar?
Why couldn't this epiphany be the best experience of their (short) lives?

At the end of the day, the experience wasn't intended to be a happy clappy situation. It was people, at the lowest end of tzimtzum, experiencing something that was almost beyond their capability to experience. It was awesome, not bouncy joyful.

It was done this way to teach that eventually people will be able to develop ability to live with strong reverence for doing mitzvos, which will create a just world.

@Yehuda You could make similar points about Krias Yam Suf, yet it seems that was more joyous than dreadful.

@shmosel you're right! They didn't say Shirah upon seeing their God!

אהבה needs to be built on a bedrock of יראה.

was also a dreadful and frightening experience just like the rest of the Haredi conduct -Am I the only person who finds this line mildly offensive?

@chortkov2 He claimed that the word Haredi reflects the fact that the Ultra-Orthodox mentality/conduct is based on fear and anxiety, just as portrayed with the Ten Commandments. While I disagree that most Haredis feel that way in practice, I agree with the argument - deep down the UO world is founded on fear of punishment. And I can back it up with my personal experience in the Jerusalem Haredi community.

I must disagree. The 'Ultra Orthodox' community I was raised in portrays Judaism as vibrant, joyful, warm, meaningful, purposeful. Judaism is seen as a privilege, not merely an obligation.

@chortkov2 What instinctive emotion do you experience when unintentionally breaking a serious prohibition, such as eating non-Kosher or breaking Shabbos? How do you connect with the Tachanun and Yom Kippur prayers? is it "out of privilege"? I agree that many contemporary Haredis developed a sense of self-esteem and even pride, but all that on the firm foundation of "God-fearing" as frequently quoted "ראשית חכמה יראת יהוה".

@AlBerko Are you saying that non-Haredim don’t keep kosher, Shabbat, pray תחנון, or observe Yom Kippur? None of that is specific to Haredim. Additionally, the instinctive emotion I feel during such occurrences as in your comment is guilt. I, like all educated Jews, love Hashem. Hashem doesn’t want certain things, and if I do them anyway, I feel bad, because they offends the One I love with all my being. It has nothing to do with punishment; “eternal damnation” is a Christian concept, and it’s not like I’ll be struck by lightning every time I mess up. Get your ideas straight.

@AlBerko Obviously, there are many radical Haredi groups. They don’t represent normal Jews. There are, in fact, normal Haredi communities filled with good people who aren’t extremist idiots. (I say this as an observant Modern Orthodox Mizrahi Jew).

@AlBerko - Accidental sinning invokes shock, sadness, shame. Tachanun in my life is an opportunity, not a burden; Yom Kippur is a day of positivity - a Godly gift of returning to a relationship sullied by our betrayal.

It saddens me that your perception of 'God-fearing' is somehow contradictory to a healthy, joyful relationship with Hashem and Torah.

@chortkov2 Lurianic Kabbala distinguishes between two levels of יראה as relative to אהבה - one below and one above. So the first level is a basic "fear of punishment". The other is some kind of "fear of separation from God". According to Rabbi Moshe Luria, only a small percentage of people worship YHWH out of love and only a couple of dozen reach the level or יראה you refer to. What you describe is a cognitive dissonance of the Jews living in the Christian environment, trying to level up with the concept of "love for God".

The definition of negative depends on perspective. For a former powerless slave who just ran from an excruciating bondage it was very important and encouraging to align oneself with the power greater than one could imagine. Indeed, the Arab tribes even today make alignments with stronger powers at all costs in a fight for survival. On the other hand, for a person grown in the West the description of Matan Torah in the Talmud may appear coercive. There is a discussion in the Gemara and the comments (brought in Artscroll) for why coercion took place.
The experience at Mt. Sinai is described in gemara Shabbos 88a: the Holy One, Blessed be He, overturned the mountain above the Jews like a tub, and said to them: If you accept...the Torah, excellent, and if not, there will be your burial....Rav Aḥa bar Ya’akov said: From here there is a substantial caveat to the obligation to fulfill the Torah....The Jewish people can claim that they were coerced into accepting the Torah, and it is therefore not binding.
Tosafos: And even though they had already first said, "We will do," before, "and we will hear" (a valid commitment) - perhaps they would retract when they would see the great fire [on the mountain], such that their souls departed as in Gemara on Shabbos 88b. (I.e. their commitment could have been rescinded on the basis that it was made without knowledge of awesome consequences - Artscroll).
The proof is given from other nations: And [regarding] that which it said [that the other nations said in their defense for not accepting the Torah] in the first chapter of Avodah Zarah (2b), "Did you overturn the mountain above us like a tub?" - which implies that if He had overturned [it] above them, they would not have had an answer/excuse (for refusing to accept the Torah). Whereas here it said that it [itself] is a substantial caveat to the Torah: That means [that it is not an excuse, but rather a reason that would have made them guilty] for their not accepting it (the Torah). But regarding their not keeping it, it would have been an [excuse].
Maharal, Tiferes Israel ch. 32, asks, why did G-d not first wait to see if the people would renege, and then force their acceptance if necessary? He answers that G-d wanted that the Jewish answer "We will do and we will hear", which was made out of love, to be binding forever. Hence, He did not want to risk drawing a new coercion.
Midrash Tanchuma, Noach 3, states that the words "We will do and we will hear" signaled acceptance only of the Written law. The people were reluctant to accept the Oral Law which requires effort and discipline in its study and observance. I.e. coercion was in regard to Oral law.
The next comment of Tosafos shows that eventually Jewish people accepted both Written and Oral Torah willingly. A substantial caveat to the Torah: And [regarding] that which it said in Nedarim (25a), that Moshe made a covenant with Israel about the Torah and the commandments and had them take an oath about this; and in the chapter [entitled] Elu Ne'emanim (Sotah 37b), that they accepted all of the Torah at Mount Gerizim and at Mount Eival - Rabbenu Tam says that it was by way of a command [from God]; so behold it is like [it was] against their will. But at the time of Achashverosh, they accepted [it] with their consent from love of the miracle. And [regarding] that which Yehoshua made a covenant with them to serve God - there they only accepted not to worship idolatry. As it is written (Yehoshua 24:), "God forbid for us to forsake the Lord"; and all of the matter [there] implies this.

I have little idea what you're talking about. What's "its grandeur really seduced some people into making a decision they could have refused to make"? Your second part does not explain the fear either. As per Eliyahoo's example, the same frightening element exists here - no fun, no joy.

@AlBerko rethought and rewritten

Thank you, I appreciate your effort. If I read you right, you say that Matan Torah "had to be coercive" and therefore unpleasant. I disagree, coercion is just one creative hermeneutics, surely not the Pshat. can I propose I post a new question "Why Matan Torah had to be coercive?" and you move this beautiful answer there?

I agree, but please first explain more in your question what do you mean by "negative". I am at a loss of finding the negativity.

OK, do you agree that חרדה is a negative emotion? Do you agree that God warning people to be killed if touched the mountain creates negative feelings? The outcome was also negative, people couldn't stand it out of fear and anxiety.

@AlBerko look, I hear your point. People take as something negative many different things. In the Torah חרדה is only mentioned in regards to a weak and blind Yitzchak after he realized that he blessed Yaakov and now he has Eisav in his room demanding a blessing, which he cannot not give. So by the same logic, we could use חרדה with respect to giving of the Torah, if after we received the Torah, Bnei Yishmael and Bnei Eisav showed up and started demanding receiving it too as a weapon against us.

@AlBerko certainly parents should not put exessive fear in children. However, that was a result of WW2, when many older people were dead and few could teach younger people. R. Shlomo Wolbe wrote a great book "Planting & Building. Raising a Jewish Child" on this subject. There are many other such books. Also about values lost in Holocaust of WW2, R. Yom Tov Schwarz "Eyes to See" - a truly good and little known book.

The Midrash says:

The whole world was created only for the sake of the Torah… God saw a single rose-colored flower, to wit, Israel. He took it and smelled it, when He gave [the Israelites] the Ten Commandments; His spirits were calmed when they said:
We will do, and we will listen. [Exodus 24:7]
[At that time], the Holy One said, “The orchard shall be saved on account of this flower. For the sake of the Torah and of Israel the world shall be saved.” [Vayikra Rabbah 23:3]

From this, the tradition emerged that Mount Sinai blossomed with flowers right before the giving of the Torah.
One of the five traditions of Shavuot, when we celebrate the giving of the Torah, is to decorate homes and synagogues with plants, flowers and tree branches. The earliest mention of this custom is by the Maharil, from 15th-century Germany.

I don't see how this answers the question.

Stunning Midrash!!
